# Cannot Boot - VFS: Unable to mount root / need help with GRUB2 boot

Tags: boot, grub2

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS server.  Today I ran `apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, and apt-get dist-upgrade`.

When I rebooted, something failed - the OS would not load.  The last part of the error says:

```
[end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
```

When I enter the GNU GRUB  ***Advanced options for Ubuntu** screen,  I can choose 4.4.0-59-generic or 4.4.0-57-generic (and many lower numbers).

When I choose 4.4.0-57-generic - my Ubuntu server loads and seems fine.

I have two questions:
1) Can someone explain what happened, and possibly, give me an idea of how I could try fix it?

2) If option one is complicated - can someone explain how I can permanently boot into 4.4.0-57-generic without having to manually select from this menu?

Comment: what happened: your kernel was upgraded. This caused something to break on your machine. Can you tell us what machine you are using?

Comment: It is a 10 year old Dell XPS 400, dual core Intel pentium-D.

Comment: can you give me more information prior to the error?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to question #2 here:
https://sites.google.com/site/installationubuntu/general-issues/grub-default-older-kernel

I edited the GRUB_DEFAULT line in /etc/default/grub
GRUB_DEFAULT="1>2" to skip through the menu to the last best kernel.